# Verifying staking addresses of voter addresses in code returning no staking addresses (code issuse)

Tags: staking, vote-account

Hey guys I am trying to get a list of addresses staking to a validator. I can verify on an explorer there are addresses, but in my code I always return no addresses associated. Can anyone see what Im doing wrong?

```
import requests


def get_stake_accounts_by_vote_account(vote_account_address):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "getProgramAccounts",
        "params": [
            "Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111",
            {
                "encoding": "jsonParsed",
                "commitment": "confirmed",
                "filters": [
                    {"memcmp": {"offset": 32, "bytes": vote_account_address}},
                    {"dataSize": 200}  # Stake account data length
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", headers=headers, json=payload)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(
            f"Error: Unable to fetch data from Solana network. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return []
    return response.json().get('result', [])


def main():
    # List of validator vote account addresses
    validator_vote_accounts = [
        "8EfUy8zz6DF2iTMQCUe4QAnoq4jVUzfU1yvZMCr2yJ7m",
    ]

    for vote_account in validator_vote_accounts:
        print(f"Stake Accounts for Validator {vote_account}:")
        stake_accounts = get_stake_accounts_by_vote_account(vote_account)

        if not stake_accounts:
            print("No stake accounts found for this validator.")
            continue

        for account in stake_accounts:
            account_address = account['pubkey']
            lamports = account['account']['data']['parsed']['info']['stake']['delegation']['stake']
            print(f"Account: {account_address}, Staked Lamports: {lamports}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This returns nothing, but we can see there are staking addresses via the explorer https://solanabeach.io/validator/8EfUy8zz6DF2iTMQCUe4QAnoq4jVUzfU1yvZMCr2yJ7m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close! You're fetching all the stake accounts, but your `offset` of 32 is incorrect. If we look at the `StakeStateV2` enum at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/47a98ebf0bc79fa4912d3fabdf522155cf2eda5e/sdk/program/src/stake/state.rs#L132, we can count up to the delegated validator:

- 4 bytes for the enum discriminant
- 120 bytes for the `Meta` (8 bytes for u64, 64 bytes for `Authorized`, 48 bytes for the `Lockup`)
- and you're right at the `voter_pubkey` in the `Delegation` struct in the `Stake` struct!

So you should use `124` for the offset instead.